# How to Make a Border in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a certain area of my game have a border around it and used one size to keep changing around my code so that it worked for one size:

Here is the code:

```
# screen, xpos, ypos, height, width, border width, color
def draw_borders(s, x, y, h, w, bw, c):
    draw(s, color, x, y, w, bw)
    draw(s, color, x, y, bw, h)
    draw(s, color, x, h+bw, w, bw)
    draw(s, color, w, y+bw, bw, h)
# draw is just a function that calls pygame.draw.rect with all the values given


def draw(s, color, x, y, w, h):
    pygame.draw.rect(s, color, (x,y,w,h))
```

The data that this works with is:

```
# sw = screen width
# I have my default sw at 500x500 but it works for any window size
draw_borders(10, 10, sw-20 sh-20)
```

The problem is that the boxes do not align, so the 4 boxes that make the border dont match up to make the actual border, when the values are any different so I cannot get a box that isn't defined to the window size.

So I guess my question(s) are:

1- Is there an easier way to make borders?

2- If not how do I make it so the borders align no matter what the data passed into it is?

Comment: What do you mean by "do not align"? What exactly happens, and how is it different from what should happen? What do you need to do to cause the problem? (For example, does it look right until you resize the window and then it doesn't update?) Pictures help. Also, please make sure that your example of using `draw_borders` exactly matches how your code does it.

Comment: What is `w` and `h`? Is it a width and height or is it coordinate? Can you show the implementation of `draw`?

Comment: Can you please show the `draw` function.

Comment: @QuiYU done (i dont know if the tag worked tho)

Comment: @Rabbid76 w and h is indeed width and height, i tried to show this with the comment above the function (again no idea if the tag worked)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel ive edited to show what i mean by align and the function ```draw_borders``` had one little mistake so i have added that as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to draw a border, then you can directly use [`pygame.draw.rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) by setting the `width` argument.

```py
def draw_borders(s, x, y, w, h, bw, c):
    pygame.draw.rect(s, c, (x, y, w, h), bw)
```

or alternatively drawing a closed polygon

```py
def draw_borders(s, x, y, w, h, bw, c):
    pygame.draw.lines(s, c, True, [(x, y), (x+w, y), (x+w, y+h), (x, y+h)], bw)
```

[image]

---

If you want to get rid of the lack at the corners, then you have to stitch the border by 4 rectangles:

```py
def draw_borders(s, x, y, w, h, bw, c):
    pygame.draw.rect(s, c, (x, y, w, bw))
    pygame.draw.rect(s, c, (x, y+h-bw, w, bw))
    pygame.draw.rect(s, c, (x, y, bw, h))
    pygame.draw.rect(s, c, (x+w-bw, y, bw, h))
```

or by 4 separate lines:

```py
def draw_borders(s, x, y, w, h, bw, c):
    pygame.draw.line(s, c, (x-bw//2+1, y), (x+w+bw//2, y), bw)
    pygame.draw.line(s, c, (x-bw//2+1, y+h), (x+w+bw//2, y+h), bw)
    pygame.draw.line(s, c, (x, y-bw//2+1), (x, y+h+bw//2), bw)
    pygame.draw.line(s, c, (x+w, y-bw//2+1), (x+w, y+h+bw//2), bw)
```

[image]

Comment: That has worked perfectly thank you! I went for the second option in the end only because of the corners!

Comment: Could you also do it by drawing each side as a thick line?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, but that makes no difference. I've extended the answer.